# TypeError 'x' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, django, typeerror

Im getting the error

> ```
> 'CampSite' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
> ```

when I save a new CampCon entry in the admin interface.  I have one application called campsites that handles the database of campsites, and I have another application called content that handles reviews. I am very new to Django and this is my first non-tutorial based project.  I have been racking my brain and searching the web for an answer with no luck. Thank you in advance for your help. 
Here is my campsite model:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class CampSite(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    showers = models.BooleanField()
    flush = models.BooleanField()
    rv = models.BooleanField()
    lonlat = models.PointField(null=True, blank=True)

    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is the content model:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from campsites.models import CampSite
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from activities.models import Activities


class CampCon(models.Model):
    campsite = models.ForeignKey(CampSite)
    trip = models.ForeignKey('Trip')
    Date = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    overall_review = models.TextField()
    facilities_review = models.IntegerField()
    things_to_do = models.IntegerField()
    privacy = models.IntegerField()
    beauty = models.IntegerField()
    overall_rating = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.campsite

class ImageDB(models.Model):
    campsite = models.ForeignKey(CampSite)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/home/bobby/Pictures/CampThat')
    date_uploaded = models.DateField()
    date_taken = models.DateField()
    trip = models.ForeignKey('Trip')
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activities)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.campsite

class Trip(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    blog = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class ActivityCon(models.Model):
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    overall_review = models.TextField()
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activities)
```

And here is the full Traceback:

```
    Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/content/campcon/add/

Django Version: 1.5
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'campsites',
 'auth',
 'trips',
 'content',
 'activities',
 'django.contrib.admin')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  116.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  367.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  202.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  208.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  958.                 self.log_addition(request, new_object)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in log_addition
  525.             action_flag     = ADDITION
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/models.py" in log_action
  18.         e = self.model(None, None, user_id, content_type_id, smart_text(object_id), object_repr[:200], action_flag, change_message)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/content/campcon/add/
Exception Value: 'CampSite' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your issue is that your `__unicode__` functions are returning model objects when they need to be returning unicode strings.

You can achieve this by adding the `unicode()` function to your `__unicode__` methods:

```
class CampCon(models.Model):
    campsite = models.ForeignKey(CampSite)
    trip = models.ForeignKey('Trip')
    Date = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    overall_review = models.TextField()
    facilities_review = models.IntegerField()
    things_to_do = models.IntegerField()
    privacy = models.IntegerField()
    beauty = models.IntegerField()
    overall_rating = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.campsite)

class ImageDB(models.Model):
    campsite = models.ForeignKey(CampSite)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/home/bobby/Pictures/CampThat')
    date_uploaded = models.DateField()
    date_taken = models.DateField()
    trip = models.ForeignKey('Trip')
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activities)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.campsite)
```

This will call `CampSite.__unicode__` which will return `campsite.name`.

Answer (score 2):

Use this method instead:

```
   def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.campsite)
```

Answer (score 0):

This also happens if you do it like this:

```
event_name = CharField(max_length = 250)
```

and not like this: (the right way)

```
event_name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
```

*might be helpful to someone*

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the first hit on Google: I got a similar error (`'ItemGroup' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`) when doing the following:

```
class ItemGroup(models.Model):
    groupname = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.groupname

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    group = models.ForeignKey(MedGroup, verbose_name="Groep")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s (%s)" % (self.name, self.group[:10])
```

The last line is wrong.

It was fixed by replacing that line to `return "%s (%s)" % (self.name, self.group.groupname[:10])`