# Django OneToOne field in model's string representation

Tags: django, django-models

I try to extend django's authentification model and add some special fields to the user via a OneToOneField.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class GastroCustomer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    barcode = models.IntegerField()
    balance = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
```

This is working fine outside the admin module. But if I now start to add a new `GastroCustomer` via the admin interface I receive:
 `'User' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

If I change `__unicode__(self)` to something simple e.g.

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return "foo"
```

this error doesn't occur.
Is there a way to figure out when this user-field is in some kind of invalid state and change the string representation for this case? Can someone imagine why `__unicode__(self)` gets called before the record is 'correct'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is actually returning a model object in `__unicode__` method instead it should return unicode string, you can do this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.user)
```

This will call `User.__unicode__` which will return `user.username`. Thanks to `Nathan Villaescusa` on his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074331/typeerror-x-object-has-no-attribute-getitem).

Alternatively you can directly return the username of user in `__unicode__` method:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Comment: Thank you this works.
I thought that the user-field would forward the call to the ´__unicode__()´ of the User-Model - lesson learned.