# Django image field throws TypeError

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I'm writing a simple website using django to display some pictures. In my models, I've defined an image model, and a category model to allow me to categorize each image:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

I'd like to attach the actual image field using django's built in ImageField field `django.db.models.ImageField` which in turn uses the Python Imaging Library. I can define my models fine, but when I attempt to add an Image through the built-in admin site, I get the following error upon hitting save:
`TypeError: 'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`
I don't understand why I'm seeing this error, as I never ask for the 
**getitem**' atribute, and all of my other fields work fine – it's only the ImageField that causes the TypeError. Any Ideas? Is this possibly an issue with my PIL install? I am on a Mac, and had some minor difficulty installing PIL in the first place, but it seems to work fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A class that implements the method `__getitem__` allows you to use array indexes on it.  So `MyClass[4]` is (roughly) equivalent to `MyClass.__getitem__[4].`

Make sure you're not accidentally trying to use array indexers on your ImageField/ImageFieldFile.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with this class:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    image_location = models.ImageField(upload_to='pix/%Y/%m/%d')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    object = Manager()
```

You're seeing the error possibly because you're returning a model object (eg: Photo object):

```
#returning model object(eg: Photo object)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.image_location
```

Instead of a unicode string (eg: /Path/to/my/pix):

```
#returning unicode string instead of model object(eg: /Path/to/my/pix)
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.image_location)
```

This is the link to the StackOverflow answer that helped me: [TypeError 'x' object has no attribute '__getitem__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074331/typeerror-x-object-has-no-attribute-getitem)