# Errors using Django Awesome Avatar

Tags: python, django, user-profile, avatar

Have been trying to solve an issue using Django awesome avatar. I have used the AvatarField() in my models to save the profile pic in the UserProfile model.

```
avatar = AvatarField(upload_to=upload_profile, width=100, height=100,default = 'profiles/profile.jpg',)
```

Have also used a ModelForm to render the field to a form that is shown on the templates

```
avatar = avatar_forms.AvatarField()
```

When I try to access the user profile in admin and save, it throws an error:

```
'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Also, when I select a photo on the form in template, it does not show the crop tool that am supposed to use to resize the image.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access the file name?

You should use something like this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.image_location)
```

source: [Django image field throws TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521019/django-image-field-throws-typeerror)

Comment: Thanks for this.However, still doesn't work. Have added the unicode() for the UserProfile model but doesn't yet work. There is this line from the error page ; `Exception Location:  /home/lightweight/venv/nakuru/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awesome_avatar/fields.py in save_form_data, line 37`  . I guess the issue is with the Awesome_avatar library