# Creating sitemap on Django error: object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, django

I am very beginner here in Django. I try to generate a sitemap.xml, but I get the folllowing error:

```
   'Dish' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I have been looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074331/typeerror-x-object-has-no-attribute-getitem) but couldn't really implement any workable solution
Here is my code :

sitemap.py

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from wm.models import Dish


class todositemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "weekly"
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Dish.objects.all()

    def location(self, obj):
        return obj['slug']
```

models.py

```
class Dish(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=64)
    article = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True)
    magasines = models.ManyToManyField(Magasine, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(DishCategory, blank=True, null = True)
    geo_category = models.ManyToManyField(GeoCategory, blank=True)
    catchphrase = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null = True)
    local_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    phonetics = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='dishes', default='no-image-available.jpg', blank=True, null = True)
    picture_small = models.ImageField(upload_to='dishes', default='no-image-available.jpg', blank=True, null = True)
    date =  models.DateTimeField('date published', blank=True, null = True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    topN = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)
```

traceback:

```
Environment:
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap.xml

Django Version: 1.7
Python Version: 2.7.7
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.sites',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'wm',
  'storages',
  'django.contrib.sitemaps')
 Installed Middleware:
 ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


 Traceback:
 File "C:\Users\laurent\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
   111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\laurent\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sitemaps\views.py" in inner
   16.         response = func(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\laurent\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sitemaps\views.py" in sitemap
   67.                                       protocol=req_protocol))
 File "C:\Users\laurent\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sitemaps\__init__.py" in get_urls
   96.             loc = "%s://%s%s" % (protocol, domain, self.__get('location', item))
 File "C:\Users\laurent\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sitemaps\__init__.py" in __get
   60.             return attr(obj)
 File "C:\Users\laurent\Desktop\venv\wm_v2\wmsite\sitemap.py" in location
   16.                 return obj['slug']

 Exception Type: TypeError at /sitemap.xml
 Exception Value: 'Dish' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: 2.7.7 as per traceback

Comment: @lauWM Your model `Dish` doesnot contains `slug` attribute.

Comment: Added     def location(self, obj):
        return obj['slug'] but doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors here.

`obj` will be a Dish instance, as returned by the `items` method. Model instances are like any other class instance, they use dot notation rather than square-bracket notation.

Secondly, your Dish model doesn't have a `slug` attribute. So you can't return it from the method.

Comment: `obj.slug`, exactly as you would do anywhere else in a template or a view. But you don't have a slug attribute, so this won't work anyway.

Comment: I added  def location(self, obj): return obj['slug']  to the dish class, it is correct ?

Comment: No, of course not. Why would it be correct? You're still making the same two mistakes, plus there's no reason why you would ever call `dish.location`.